# Akka-HTTP Request-Level Client-Side API creating too many threads

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, akka-http

I am seeing an odd behavior in a microservice using Akka-HTTP (10.1.11 / Scala 2.12.9) for consuming external services through the `Http().singleRequest` method.

The observed behavior is that we're creating a thread pool per a set of outgoing requests. This TP contains three threads that are created as part of the Akka's ***default dispatcher*** but those are never used (they stands in **Park** state until their EOL). The TP recycling happens in a non-deterministic way, meaning that some threads are killed after 200.000ms, for example, while the next set of threads belonging to a newly created TP are killed in a lower or upper timeframe (might indicate that it's not following [the akka.http.client.idle-timeout](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html) configuration).

This is how a set of threads of the `default-dispatcher` looks like:

[image: Finished threads]

And this is the overall thread count (created) through a 2-hour span:

[image]

A closer look (see the *0ms* usage time for those threads):

[image]

So, my questions here are:

1. Am I looking in the right direction? I mean, is this indeed a *thread pool leak* or is this the supposed behavior of Akka-HTTP?
2. If this is the intended behavior, why is it desirable to spawn new threads per request? Isn't this too expensive to perform? And why those newly spawned threads keeps unused?
3. If it's not the intended behavior, where should I look at?

It's worth to mention that we're using the following configuration:

```
http {
    # https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/pool-overflow.html
    host-connection-pool {
      max-connections = 16
      max-open-requests = 64
      response-entity-subscription-timeout = 10s
      max-connection-lifetime = 60s
    }
  }
```

Finally, the [Request-Level Client-Side API docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-level.html) shed some light, but I'm not entirely sure about the inner workings of this approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no direct relationship between akka-http and threads. Akka-http uses the dispatchers from its ActorSystem. Did you reconfigure Akka's dispatcher? None of the threads shown in the screenshot have typical names of Akka's default thread pool.

Comment: @jrudolph No, I didn't. And what should be the name of the Akka's default thread pool? Just for future reference

Comment: The ones in the last screenshot look like the normal ones. They usually have `default-dispatcher` in the name.

Comment: The `pool` and `commonPool` ones might come from Scala's `ExecutionContext.global` or from Java usages.

Comment: The `default-blocking-io-dispatcher` ones are part of a fixed thread pool, so it's probably expected that they are parking most of the time (if you are not running any workloads that automatically use the IO dispatcher, like akka-stream's FileIO).

Comment: Now the question is which threads are see as fluctuating? If it are really the `default-dispatcher` ones, they are by default configured for a max size of 3 x cpu cores / threads. There will always at least be one but the rest is scaled up and down as the ForkJoinPool implementation sees fit.

Comment: So, the answer to 1. would be, yes, some fluctuation is expected when you have a volatile load pattern.

Comment: Wrt 2. there are only spawned as many threads as configured at most , so the number of threads is bounded. They are only killed after a long time of idling so it not be a problem.

Comment: @jrudolph Thanks for your answer! -- The fluctuating threads are the one under the `default-dispatcher` and `default-blocking-io-dispatcher`. As I've mentioned previously, both TPs are idle ("parked") during their lifetime. There are always three threads per TP created, no more than that.

Comment: Also, it's worth to mention that what initially led me to think about a leak is the fact that those pools aren't never constant. You've mentioned that a FJP will have at least one thread and the rest are scaled up and down, but in this case the entire pool is shut down and shortly after a new pool with three threads is spawned. A production load, during a 24 period can have a thousand (10-20K) threads total count, which I still understand as an abnormal behavior (given that none of the threads of the dispatchers are alive for too much time).

Comment: I figured a potential (default) configuration reason for the behavior, see https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/29238

Comment: @jrudolph Thank you! I'm actually digging into a potential implementation issue of a circuit-breaking mechanism (on top of Akka's implementation) that might be also contributing to this behavior. I will still take a look at your workaround though :) -- In any case I'll report back here.